# Track my contract as its owner

Tags: contract-design

I wonder if there is a way to keep track of my smart contract as an owner of it.
Like get a full dynamic report regarding each and every action happened on it since it has been created ?

Answer (score 5):

It does not matter if you're an owner or not as all information is public for everyone.

Easiest way to accomplish this is to add `events` logging to your functions. After that you need a backend system (outside blockchain) which monitors the contract for these events and based on those events you can create whatever reports you wish.

If you wish, you can also utilize somewhat ready tools for this, such as https://etherscan.io/apis